# Why does the terminal say that the new version 16 needs to download 1.9 GB of data

Tags: upgrade, updates

I ran the command  sudo do-release-upgrade on the terminal and it says

> 134 packages are going to be removed. 1068 new packages are going to 
>   be installed. 2246 packages are going to be upgraded. 
>   You have to download a total of 1,877 M

It also says that it would take 4 hours for that to happen with my connection. Should I be worried about that??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. because it will download all packages you installed, replace it with newer versions, and that totals up to 1.877Gb.
2. 4 hours. Should you be worried? How good is your internet connection? If it is good go for it. Otherwise I would not. You could always just download the iso using a torrent if your connection is bad, burn it to an USB and re-install with the "replace current Ubuntu and keep my documents" option.

   Mind though: if you run out of power we expect you to have a backup of your  personal data.

Comment: Since `/usr/bin/do-release-upgrade` is a Python script, one can read it and see that it's an "APT tool", and uses the `apt` structure. This leads me to hope that it would respect `Configuration Item: APT::Get::Download-Only` (see `man apt-get;man apt.conf`. You could set `APT::Get::Download-Only`, run `do-release-upgrade` repeatedly until all the packages are downloaded, reset `APT::Get::Download-Only` and run `do-release-upgrade` one final time. I HAVE NOT TESTED THIS!

Comment: Would all my applications as well as the configuration files remain as well?and how do I install the iso?

Comment: 1. if you upgrade all the PPA's will be disabled and that software will NOT be updated. You need to do that afterwards 2. using an ISO: the same as how you installed your current OS. Burn ISO to USB. Boot from it. Pick the correct option that does not format your /home/. Plus you make a backup before messing with the OS.